Getting DB2 stored procedure output parameter using symfony and doctrine
I am refactoring plain PHP code in symfony (5) + doctrine
my mode is something like:
$sql = "CALL my_store_procedure (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = db2_prepare($db, $sql);

    $p1 = "p1";
    $p2 = "p2";
    $p3 = "p3";
    $p4 = "p4";
    $p5 = ;
    
    @db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, "p1", DB2_PARAM_IN);
    @db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, "p2", DB2_PARAM_IN);
    @db2_bind_param($stmt, 3, "p3", DB2_PARAM_IN);
    @db2_bind_param($stmt, 4, "p4", DB2_PARAM_IN);
    @db2_bind_param($stmt, 5, "p5", DB2_PARAM_OUT);

$result = @db2_execute($stmt);

this code works, and I get desired result in $p5
now, if I use doctrine and create a statement, bind parameters (specifying PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT for $p5) and execute the query, $p5 is never populated. The stored procedure is executed successfully, only the output parameter is not populated.
any hint?
thank you
Stefano

Can you edit your question to give a minimum reproducible example (no need to give the stored-procedure), and also give details of your environment, versions, components etc.?
